# GlasshFish basic authentication default username and password

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish, javabeans, basic-authentication

I'm trying to implement basic authentication in a java ee project but I cant find what the default username and password is (if there is any).

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>view.xml</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/view.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Login</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/index.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

My index page is a login form which should start the session upon successful login..this kinda work and it allows me to see the next page..Now if I dont go through the index page and I type in the url of that second page, a login window pops up but no matter what I type in there it doesnt let me see the page...I tried admin-adminadmin, admin-pass, admin-admin and others but nothing works..

Any help would be really appreciated!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found how to configure that from localhost:4848